# macOS High Sierra internet recovery is frozen

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, internet-recovery

I am using MacBook Pro 15 2015. I erased the drive and now I cannot complete the Internet recovery. It is stuck saying

```
macOS High Sierra will be installed on the disk "Untitled"
 "About 17 hours 7 minutes remaining"
```

for the past 10 hours. I did use Internet recovery in the past many times(with disk erase as well) and it was done usually in the matter of hours. This time for some reason it does not progress.
Internet connection cannot be an issue, Wi-Fi bar is complete and other devices can stream 4k easily (what was just for testing - nothing else was using bandwidth most of the time).

I tried to repeat the Internet recovery and it always eventually get stuck at some time "16 hours 4 minutes" or sometimes even just "8 minutes".

It does not become frozen, i still can click the option to cancel it (or change input language) - - just stuck with update.

I highly doubt there is a hardware failure, because it was working absolutely fine just before the disk erase and there were never any issues with it in the meantime.

Getting to apple store is very hard in my city (there are no apple stores). Is there anything else I could do to try to make it install?

Answer (score 1):

This is why it is better to first download macOS from the Apps Store to your Applications folder. You then can create a USB flash drive installer for offline installations. The instructions are given at this Apple website: [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).

You have already erased your drive so this is no longer an option on your Mac. In your case, you would now need another Mac to download High Sierra and make the installer.

> FYI: I usually have two installations of macOS per Mac. Each installation is in separate partitions. I usually the edit the `/etc/fstab` file so each installation can not access the other installation, unless I do a mount. This way I usually can avoid having to use macOS Recovery.